# AngularJs updating view in controller's event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, webpack, openstreetmap

In my app I fetch list of objects from server. I render them at a left sidebar as a list and at map (leaflet) as markers **on the same page**.
I render markers/map via service and sidebar list via controller and simple view.

When user clicks on the item from the list or on marker from the map I broadcast event from `$rootScope`.

User clicks on sidebar item -> this code is triggered:

```
// in view
<div ng-click="markerClicked(object)">...</div>

// in controller
$scope.markerClicked = function(object) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('markerClicked', object);
};
```

User clicks on marker -> this code is triggered:

```
angular.forEach(markers, function(object) {
    var _marker = L.marker([object.longitude, object.latitude],{
        clickable: true
    });

    _marker.on('click', function(e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('markerClicked', object)
    });

    _marker.addTo(service.map);
    service.layer.addLayer(_marker);
});
```

---

I catch this event only in one controller:

```
// I also tried $rootScope.$on()
$scope.$on('markerClicked', function(event, object) {
    $scope.object = object;
    $scope.hidden = false;
    console.log('event fires');
});
```

`$scope.hidden` here is a flag for conditional rendering the modal window (popup).

The problem here is that whenever I click on sidebar item or map marker, console logs `'event fires'` and other code lines work as well, **BUT**
modal window appears ONLY if I click on sidebar item.

In other words, when I click on marker I get `'event fires'` in dev console, I see that `$scope.hidden` equals to `false` **BUT** modal window does not appears.

If somebody has met similar issue please point me what am I doing wrong.

---

I use webpack, maybe this also matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$scope.$on('markerClicked', function(event, object) {

    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.object = object;
       $scope.hidden = false;
    })
    console.log('event fires');
});
```

Comment: thank you, that worked!

However, I had to use ["safe apply" approach](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js) here.

Anyway, thanks again.